# plottnig lines on a 3d surface matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to plot lines on a 3d surface in matlab. I wrote two scripts one to plot the surface and one to plot the lines on the surface.
script1

```
function figHandle = plotFunction(funchandle, a , b)
    x_vec = -a:.1:a;
    y_vec = -b:.1:b;
    figHandle = figure();
    [X,Y] = meshgrid(x_vec, y_vec);
    Z = [];
    z_temp = [];
    for i = x_vec
        for j = y_vec
            z_temp =[z_temp; funchandle([i; j])];
        end;
        Z = [Z, z_temp];
        z_temp = [];
    end;
    h = surf(X,Y,Z);
    set(h, 'edgecolor', 'none');
    %colormap gray;
    colorbar;
    view(0,90);
end
```

script2

```
function plotStep(figHandle,funcHandle, P1, P2)
   figure(figHandle);
   hold on;
   plot3(P1(1), P1(2), funcHandle([P1(1);P1(2)]), 'r*');
   if ~isequal(P1,P2)
      Z = [];
      X = [];
      Y = [];
      d = [P2(1)-P1(1), P2(2) - P1(2)];
      if (P1(1) < P2(1))
          X = P1(1):0.0001:P2(1);
          if (P1(2) ~= P2(2))
              Y = X.*(d(2)/d(1))+(P1(2)-(d(2)/d(1))*P1(1));
          else
              for i = X
                  Y = [Y, P1(2)];
              end
          end
      elseif P1(1) > P2(1)
          X = P1(1):-0.0001:P2(1);
          if (P1(2) ~= P2(2))
              Y = X.*(d(2)/d(1))+(P1(2)-(d(2)/d(1))*P1(1));
          else
              for i = X
                  Y = [Y, P1(2)];
              end
          end
      else
          if P1(2) < P2(2)
              Y = P1(2):0.0001:P2(2);
              for i = Y
                  X = [X, P1(1)];
              end
          else
              Y = P1(2):-0.0001:P2(2);
              for i = Y
                  X = [X, P1(1)];
              end
          end
      end

      for i = 1:length(X)
          Z = [Z;funcHandle([X(i);Y(i)])];
      end
      plot3(X, Y, Z, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);

   end
```

My problem is no matter how close too each other I make the points which form the line after zooming in on the line it does not seem to be continuous.
[image: before zooming in]
[image: after zooming in]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to fix this is to raise the line a little bit off the surface,

```
plot3(X, Y, Z+1, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

but you may have to experiment with the offset. It can sometimes help to make the line a little wider, and to try the different renderers as well.

Comment: Thanks @David, this might do it. But I got a different idea. The problem might appear, because matlab chooses a high degree polinomial to fit the points which form the line. This causes some of the linepoints to be below the 3d surface where it flattens out. If I could change that approximation method, so that matlab would just use a linear approximation between the points then this would solve the problem for all convex functions. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could reduce the effect by plotting more data points. If you don't have/can't get more data you could create more data by linear interpolation.